# Shorten a number of lists based on a collective max length, moving excess to new lists

Tags: python

I have N lists of varying lengths. These lists contain items to display in a UI, and I have have a maximum UI budget of X. Any excess items go into a dropdown menu instead. What I need to do is move items from the lists into their "overflow" equivalent so that the total length of all the lists is equal or less than the max length. I want to make sure that no list is shortened less than what's necessary, and that they end up as close to equal length as possible. Example:

I have three lists, `l1=range(10)`, `l2=range(15)` and `l3=range(20)` and `maxLength=40`. What I need to get from this is `l1` and `l2` left as-is and `l3` shortened to 15 items, since 10+15+15=45. If `l1=range(15)` instead, I should end up with two lists with 13 items and one with 14.

At the moment, I have a function that uses a while loop to accomplish this, like so:

```
def shortenLists(maxLength, *input_lists):
    overflows = [[] for n in input_lists]

    while sum(len(l) for l in input_lists) > maxLength:
        longestList = max(input_lists, key=len)
        index = input_lists.index(longestList)
        overflows[index].append(longestList.pop())

    [o.reverse() for o in overflows]
    return input_lists, overflows
```

This does basically seem to work, but I don't particularly like using a while loop for something like this; it seems it ought to be relatively simple to just figure out how many items to remove from each list. This method also relies on using the list.index() method to find the index of the longest list in the input in order to add the items to the right overflow buffer, which seems like a bit of a hack.

The function returns a tuple of two lists, with the cropped input lists in order and the overflow buffers in the same order. I'm not sure if this is the best approach, of it it's better to zip them up so it returns ((list, overflow), (list, overflow)) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best would be to start with the shortest list and not the longest. In that case, any list that is shorter than the average and ideal number of items per list, can be copied completely and the remaining space will be recalculated and reassigned among the other lists.

```
def shortenLists(maxLength, *input_lists):
    overflows = [[] for n in input_lists]
    result_lists = [[] for n in input_lists]

    for i in xrange(len(input_lists)):
        remaining = [l for idx, l in enumerate(input_lists) if not len(result_lists[idx])]
        shortestList = min(remaining, key=len)
        idxSL = input_lists.index(shortestList)
        numElems = int(math.floor(maxLength/len(remaining)))
        toCopy = min(numElems, len(shortestList))
        result_lists[idxSL] = shortestList[:toCopy]
        if numElems < len(shortestList):
            overflows[idxSL] = shortestList[numElems:]
        maxLength -= toCopy
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation of your code:

```
def shortenLists(maxLength, *input_lists):
    item_per_list = maxLength / len(input_lists)
    overflows = []
    for (i, l) in enumerate(input_lists):
        overflows.append(l[item_per_list:])
        l[item_per_list:] = []
    return input_lists, overflows
```

Comment: That doesn't allow a longer list to use the extra space left by a shorter list, though. Suppose we have two lists, one with 5 items and one with 15. Our maxLength is 14. Using your method, we'd end up with one list with 5 items and one list with 7 items. With my method, the extra space left by the first list can be grabbed by the second list. I've had a few situations where I've had one or two items in one category and 10-20 in another category, and I want to be able to use the extra space left by the shorter lists to display more items in the longer lists.

Answer (score 0):

I think for my purposes, the solution is to actually use a `while` loop. I extended my code a little bit by simply slicing the lists first so that no list is longer than `maxLength`, like this:

```
for index, l in enumerate(new_lists):
    overflows[index] = new_lists[index][maxLength:]
    new_lists[index] = new_lists[index][:maxLength]
```

I do have a bit of a follow-up question about slicing, though... is it possible to slice in place? I noticed that when I did it like this:

```
for index, this_list in enumerate(new_lists):
    overflows[index] = this_list[maxLength:]
    this_list = this_list[:maxLength]
```

It would actually create new copies of everything, which obviously doesn't work very well for my purposes. Hence the use of indexes. Anyway, back to the main topic...

When looping over all the lists once first and making sure that none of them are longer than the max length, the execution time for clamping 50 lists of 10**5 items each went from about 90 seconds to 0.2 seconds. For my purposes, this is more than enough; I will probably never have a list of items longer than a few hundred, and usually no more than about a dozen lists. So my execution time is really on the order of a few centiseconds for the amount of data I need to operate on.

If anyone has any further advice for how to get away from the nasty while loop business for the sheer sake of *niceness* of the code, that would be much appreciated, but for now I think the question is basically answered. If anyone's interested, here's the code:

```
def shortenLists(maxLength, *input_lists):
    #create copies of all input lists
    new_lists = [list(l) for l in input_lists]
    #create overflow lists
    overflows = [[] for n in input_lists]

    #make sure no list is longer than maxLength
    for index, l in enumerate(new_lists):
        overflows[index] = new_lists[index][maxLength:]
        new_lists[index] = new_lists[index][:maxLength]
        overflows[index].reverse()

    #loop until the total length is less or equal than maxLength
    while sum(len(l) for l in new_lists) > maxLength:
        #longest list's index
        index = max(enumerate(new_lists), key = lambda tup: len(tup[1]))[0]
        #move last item from new_lists[index] to overflow[index],
        #shortening it by 1
        overflows[index].append(new_lists[index].pop())

    #reverse all overflow lists, because "pop" is added from the back
    [o.reverse() for o in overflows]
    return zip(new_lists, overflows)
```

Comment: `is it possible to slice in place?` Yes, instead of `this_list = this_list[:maxLength]`, you can do `this_list[:] = this_list[:maxLength]`

Comment: Ah, of course! Because that reassigns the contents of the list, rather than the list itself. Thank you. 

I assume that it would me a fair bit slower to do a slice in place like this though, because you'll have to assign each individual thing in the list, rather than just the list object. In a simple test, it does seem slower. Not that it really matters for my purposes, but still.